# Closed form for $\sum_{k=0}^{n} k \sum_{j=0}^k {n \choose j}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem, summation-method

Closed form for $$S=\sum_{k=0}^{n} k \sum_{j=0}^k {n \choose j}$$
becomes interesting because we do not know the $j$-sum but on the other hand we can simply expand $S$ as
$$S=\sum_{k=0}^n f_k {n \choose k},$$
where $f_k$ is like frequency of $k$-th binomial coefficient. The question is what could be the closed form for $S$ with proof?

Comment: It's https://oeis.org/A089658, you can find the closed form formula there.

Comment: @Sil How do you search on oeis in order to find this result. I always see people giving out oeis results in minutes but struggles to find out how the search is performed on such arbitrary question.

Comment: @cr001 Usually I just write quick Maple code that generates first like 10 elements and then just search it in OEIS. In this case `S:=n->add(k*add(binomial(n,j),j=0..k),k=0..n)` and then `seq(S(n),n=1..10)` to get $2, 11, 42, 136, 400, 1104, 2912, 7424, 18432, 44800$ which can be just entered to the [OEIS search engine](https://oeis.org/).

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: @cr001 You are welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have :

$$S = \sum_{k=0}^n k \sum_{j=0}^k {n \choose j} = \sum_{j=0}^n \sum_{k=j}^n k {n \choose j} = \sum_{j=0}^n  {n \choose j}\sum_{k=j}^n k  = \sum_{j=0}^n  {n \choose j} \left[ \frac{n(n+1)}{2}  - \frac{(j-1)j}{2}\right]$$ $$=\frac{n(n+1)}{2} 2^n - \frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=0}^n j(j-1)  {n \choose j}  = n(n+1) 2^{n-1} - n(n-1)2^{n-3}$$ $$=2^{n-3} \left( -n(n-1) + 4n(n+1)\right) = 2^{n-3} \left( 3n^2 + 5n\right)$$